Eventually periodic behavior of an operator on finite posets
Let $P$ be a finite poset with $n$ elements. For each $a \in P$, denote by $\iota_P(a)$ the number of elements in $P$ that are strictly less than $a$. When the context is clear, we will simply write $\iota$ instead of $\iota_P$.
For each order-preserving map $f$ from $P$ to the chain $[n] = \{ 0, 1, \ldots, n \}$, define $Zf(a)$ as the size of the preimage of $[\iota(a)]$ under $f$. That is,
\begin{equation}
Zf(a) = \left| f^{-1}([\iota(a)]) \right|.
\end{equation}
It's not hard to show that $Zf$ is also order-preserving. I am interested in understanding the behavior of iterating the operator $Z$. Specifically, how to prove that for each order-preserving map $f$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{equation}
Z^{r+2} f = Z^r f
\end{equation}
whenever $r > N$?
Additionally, three key properties of $Z$ are possibly related to this problem:

When $P$ is a chain, $Z$ acts as an involution. That is, for any order-preserving map $f \colon P \to [n]$, we have $Z^2f = f$.

In general, $Z$ is an order-reversing operator. That is, if $f\leq g$ (i.e., $f(a) \leq g(a)$ for all $a \in P$), then $Zf\geq Zg$.

For a given $f$, if there exists some $t>0$ such that $Z^t f=f$, then $t$ must be even.


Any insights or references regarding the iteration behavior of $Z$ would be greatly appreciated.
